# Laravel linking image to base path

Tags: php, laravel, public-html

looking to move all of my user uploaded images outside of the public view.

I have my structure as so:

```
Mamp
  htdocs
    buildsanctuary
      /app
      /public_html
        / images
      /user_images
```

I used to link to images with:

```
{{ asset('/')}} images/linktoimage.jpeg
```

However I have now linked like so:

```
<?php echo base_path() ?> /user_images/linktoimage.jpeg
```

This does not work however and it shows as the image could not be found.

When checking the link to the image in a browser it shows:

```
http://localhost/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/buildsanctuary/user_images/linktoimage.jpeg
```

So im not sure why this isnt working? Any ideas?

Comment: Because files outside the public directory are not directly accessible for the browser. You would need to add a route that then reads and returns the image.

Comment: Ah thats logical. Okay thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because files outside the public directory are not directly accessible for the browser.
If you can I would leave them in the public folder. However if you really need to move them (e.g. to protect them that only authenticated users can view the pictures) You can create a route that then reads the file and returns it:

```
Route::get('user_images/{filename}', array('as' => 'user_images', function($filename){
    if(!File::exists($path)){
        App::abort(404);
    }
    $guesser = Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\MimeTypeGuesser::getInstance();
    $mimeType = $guesser->guess($path);
    return Response::make(File::get($path), 200, array('Content-Type' => $mimeType));
}))->where('filename', '.*');
```

Now you can use this in your views:

```
{{ route('user_images', 'linktoimage.jpeg') }}
```